# Dynamically integrating data from YouTube and Flickr in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a map where I want to create filters that dynamically pull data (all images and videos) from a specific YouTube and Flickr Channel/set.

Does anyone have a working example of this or some code I can try...?

Comment: I thought that it must be something that someone else will have done... so I was trying to find an example first!

Comment: Your question as it is is liable to be closed. See [How to ASK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking for something like this?

[Linking Up the Google Maps and Flickr APIs](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/linking-up-the-google-maps-and-flickr-apis--webdesign-14199)